# Return only one record with the most recent date in a group MYSQL

Tags: mysql

So, I have this query where I am trying to get the most recent sale price within several records.

```
CREATE TABLE `codes` (
  `code_father` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `code_son` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `prices` (
  `code_son` varchar(22) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
  `price` float,
  `date` date,
  KEY `code_son` (`code_son`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `codes`
(`code_father`,
`code_son`)
VALUES
('ABC000001','ADV000055');
('ABC000001','ADV000045');
('ABC000001','ADV000035');
('ABC000001','ADV000015');
('ABC000002','ADV000079');
('ABC000002','ADV000077');
('ABC000007','ADV000040');
('ABC000008','ADV000030');

INSERT INTO `prices`
(`code_son`,
`price`,
`date`)
VALUES
('ADV000055','29.99','2021-11-06');
('ADV000045','9.99','2021-12-04');
('ADV000035','9.99','2021-12-01');
('ADV000015','245.00','2021-12-06');
('ADV000045','1999.99','2021-11-03');
('ADV000035','29.99','2021-11-09');
('ADV000079','29.99','2021-11-21');
('ADV000077','29.99','2021-11-16');
('ADV000077','29.99','2021-12-04');
('ADV000040','29.99','2021-11-04');
('ADV000030','29.99','2021-11-26');
('ADV000030','29.99','2021-10-21');
```

This is the query, does not work:

```
SELECT c.code_father, c.code_son, p.price, p.date
FROM prices p
INNER JOIN (SELECT code_son, price, MAX(date)as date FROM prices GROUP BY code_son)as t1 USING(code_son, date)
LEFT JOIN codes c ON c.code_son = p.code_son
WHERE c.code_father = 'ABC000001'
```

this is what should be returned

| code_father | code_son | price | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC000001 | ADV000055 | 245.00 | 2021-12-06 |

[See the example here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=77110f4af33ea55090945b74375c2e48)

Comment: You can see the example here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=77110f4af33ea55090945b74375c2e48

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql

Comment: What means the most recent sale price? MAX price OR max date?

Comment: @Bryan change `;` to `,` in your example Insert into ... values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to change `;` to `,`, or else, only the first record will get inserted.

I guess [this may be what you are looking for](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=82da18692d875bc022d36a3894cc799e).

I just added a order by desc and limit.

```sql
SELECT c.code_father, c.code_son, p.price, p.date
FROM prices p
INNER JOIN (SELECT code_son, price, MAX(date) as date FROM prices GROUP BY code_son)as t1 USING(code_son, date)
LEFT JOIN codes c ON c.code_son = p.code_son
WHERE c.code_father = 'ABC000001'
ORDER BY p.date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

What means the most recent sale price? `MAX` price OR `MAX` date?

Search first for `MAX` price, if there are several `MAX` price, then for `MAX` Date

```
SELECT c.code_father, c.code_son, p.price, p.date
FROM prices p
INNER JOIN codes c ON p.code_son = c.code_son
ORDER BY p.price DESC, p.date DESC
LIMIT 1
```